# Are the following BNF, EBNF, Regular expressions and Lex syntax correct?

Tags: regex, lex, bnf, ebnf

I want to have BNF, EBNF, regular expression and lex syntax recognizing the following:
The string must start with one of A,B,C,D or E followed by as as many as you like of A,B,C,D,E,0,1,2,3,_ you also can have 1 or 0 of the symbol $.

So far I made:

regular expression

```
[A-E]([A-E0-9_]*[$]?[A-E0-9_]*)
```

BNF

```
<S>::= <letter><Rest>
<Rest>::=<rest1><symbol>|<rest1><symbol><rest1>|<symbol><rest1>|<rest1>|<symbol>
<rest1>::=<character><rest1>|<rest1><character>|<character>
<character>::=A|B|C|D|E|1|2|3|4|_
<letter>::=A|B|C|D|E
<symbol>::=$
```

EBNF

```
S=letter{character}[symbol]{character}
letter=|"A"|"B"|"C"|"D"|"E"|
character=|"1"|"2"|"3"|"4"|"A"|"B"|"C"|"D"|"E"|"_"
symbol="$"
```

lex

```
^[A-E][A-E0-3_]*[$]?[A-E0-3_]*$
```

Are they correct? The regular expression is 100% correct I think i have my doubts about ebnf, bnf and lex

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems.  Referring to [BNF and EBNF: What are they and how do they work?](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/bnf.html) (one of the first usable web-hits -- without a cited variation it is hard to offer specific advice...):

- the regular expression and lex disagree: you are using "^" to anchor the latter, but not the former.  lex supports alternation "|" within a parenthesized group as you have in the regular expression.
- in the BNF, the line defining `rest1` looks odd (did you mean to recur using `rest`?)
- Garshol's page does not use square brackets as you did for `[symbol]` in the EBNF.  Rather, he uses `*` and `?` (as in regular expressions).
- neither the BNF or EBNF show the use of digits 0-9
- actually, the regular expression uses 0-9, but the problem statement is 0-3

---hope that helps